# What taxes should a Middleman pays?

Tags: taxes, germany

I have the opportunity to become a middleman (i am new to the "sport"),in parallel with my current job! I live currently in Germany and i am able to buy goods in bulk from another country (in EU), transport and then sell them here in Germany.

I want to know if:

- Is it necessary to have a company to do this job?
- What kind of taxes should i pay?
- Should i pay the taxes here in Germany?
- Should i pay more than normal because of my second job?

Best regards

Comment: Are you sure this is not a random person on Internet making such offer. These are fraught with scams.

Comment: @Dheer they are not fake person because he is my friend (many years now) in fact !!! :) he wants to make an "opening" to the market here!

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the warning that this might be a scam:

You generally have to pay taxes on income/profit, not on money you move around.
That means, if you buy something for 1 million and sell it for 1,000,100, you pay taxes on the 100 which are your profit. The one million that is flowing through is of no importance.

Of course, you will need to keep records of all your transactions so you can show them in case of an audit - you cannot simply say 'I made 100, here's my tax on it'. You need to have an accounting which tracks all the inflowing and outflowing amounts, and totals up the profit.

Answer (score 1):

1: No, you need a business minimum (Gewerbe)

2: Well, you have to handle VAT (income and pay) and you have to pay income and possibly Gewerbesteuer.

3: You have to pay taxes for your business where you do it, which is generally the sale side. WHich menas germany.

4: You pay taxes. Once. If you have  2 jobs, once may have higher deductions DURING THE YEAR, but it balances out with the tax return you have to file (and may result in money back). As a business owner that is part of what makes you a business, so no lazying around (while employees may lazy around and not file returns).